# sleep in function but not block other functions and code

Tags: c++, arduino, microcontroller, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I am on esp8266 module/microcontroller. I have never wrote in C++. Now I am trying to insert my own small "non blocking" function in one file file. My function should wait 5 seconds on background and then print something. But I don't want to delay whole initialization of meInit() for 5 seconds, it should be let's say parallel "non blocking" function. How is this possible please?

```
void meInit()
{ 
  if (total > 20) total = 20;
  value = EEPROM.read(1);

  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.setTimeout(10);

  loadSettings(true);

  buildMe();

  initFirst();

  //here I need to call "non-blocking" function with no delay and process immediatelly further
  call5sFunct();  

  ...do other functions here immediatelly without 5s delay...
}

void call5sFunct()
{
  Sleep(5000);

  DEBUG_PRINTLN("I am back again");
}
```

P.S. short sample is highly appreciated :) thx

Comment: It sounds like you could use [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async).

Comment: I would consider using a fiber here https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/fiber/doc/html/index.html if you have boost

Comment: Please consider the Arduino tag. Probably not every bit of boost or the standard library is available for that target platform.

Comment: You might want to clarify that you're on a microcontroller here. You're attracting answers that seem to think you've got PC-class hardware.

Comment: Maybe have a look at hardware timers, e.g., as described here: https://deeplyembedded.org/hardware-timer-interrupts-esp8266/

Comment: @moooeeeep I don't disagree; but of all things that could be I think might be supported, that's quite high on the list since it's a single threaded async library

Comment: thank you friends, I added arduino tag into my question

Comment: you can imitate async in single thread. I asume you have while(true){} loop in main anyway, so add into this loop check if have queued tasks you should perform right now, and perform if there are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not sleep at all, but just call your function after 5 seconds have passed, in the loop function. Something like this (untested):

```
unsigned long start_time = 0;
bool call5sFunct_executed = false;

void meInit()
{ 
  if (total > 20) total = 20;
  value = EEPROM.read(1);

  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.setTimeout(10);

  loadSettings(true);

  buildMe();

  initFirst();

  // You cannot call it here, but in loop()
  // call5sFunct();  

  // ...do other functions here immediatelly without 5s delay...
}

void call5sFunct()
{
  DEBUG_PRINTLN("I am back again");
}

void loop()
{
   unsigned long loop_time = millis();
   if (!call5sFunct_executed && (loop_time - start_time >= 5000))
   {
      call5sFunct();
      call5sFunct_executed = true;
   }
   // .... the rest of your loop function ...
}
```

However, this template must be used extensively programming microcontrollers. It would be really coumbersome and error-prone to write production code like this - but it's important you get the point.

There are many libraries that make it easy to implement asynchronous operations on arduino, hiding this mechanism. For example take a look to [TaskScheduler](https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/TaskScheduler).

Google for "arduino asynchronous functions" and you will find a lot of alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::thread` to launch `call5sFunct();` in other thread, like this:

```
//...
initFirst();

//here I need to call "non-blocking" function with no delay and process immediatelly further
std::thread t1(call5sFunct);
t1.detach();  
...do other functions here immediatelly without 5s delay...

//...
```

You need to include `#include <thread>`

Comment: Did you notice the arduino tags? Do you think `std::thread` is supported on that platform?

Comment: @moooeeeep Oh no! I've missed this detail

Comment: sorry guys, I added arduino + microcontroller tags. But thank you anyways!